# Computing simplex tableu for a given basis

Tags: linear-programming, simplex, linear-algebra

I found the following problem in my book.
I know that I can compute the simplex tableau , let's call it S for a basis `X_b=(x_1, x2, x_5)^T` as `S=B^{-1}A`, if my initial problem is  :

```
 maximize f   
  s.t Ax = b
```

But **here we have a minimization problem. Can I still apply the same formula?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the formula is the same regardless of whether you are maximizing or minimizing. The difference is in how you interpret the reduced costs $c^\prime -c_B^\prime B^{-1} A.$ When maximizing, you want to pivot on variables with positive reduced cost. When minimizing, you want to pivot on variables with negative reduced cost.